# Android to PC RFCOMM Channel

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rfcomm, spp

So im working an an App that directly connect via Bluetooth to accept String commands from an RFCOMM channel and send responses.

So those are the 2 Classes i am currently working with

**Bluetooth_Manager**

```
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Reader_BluetoothManager {

    protected Reader_MainScreen main;
    protected BluetoothAdapter bAdapter;
    private Reader_AcceptThread bAccept;

    public Reader_BluetoothManager(Reader_MainScreen main) {
        this.main = main;
        initiate();
    }

    public void initiate(){
        checkForBluetooth();
        enableBluetooth();
    }

    public void log(String l){
        main.log(l);
    }

    public void checkForBluetooth(){
        bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bAdapter == null) {
            main.log("No Bluetooth supported!");
            return;
        }
        main.log("Bluetooth supported...");
    }

    public void enableBluetooth(){
        if (!bAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            main.log("Bluetooth not enabled... requesting activation");
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            main.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, main.BLUETOOTH_ENABLE_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void enableConnection(){
        main.log("Connecting...");
        if (bAccept != null)
            bAccept.interrupt();
        bAccept = new Reader_AcceptThread(this);
        bAccept.start();
    }

    public void stopConnection(){
        if (bAccept != null)
            bAccept.interrupt();
    }
}
```

And **AcceptThread**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

public class Reader_AcceptThread extends Thread{

    private BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private Reader_BluetoothManager main;


    public Reader_AcceptThread(Reader_BluetoothManager main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            serverSocket = main.bAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("XXXXXX", UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            main.log("checkPoint 1");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            main.log("checkPoint 2");
            device = socket.getRemoteDevice();
            main.log("checkPoint 3");
            main.log("connection established...");
            main.log(socket.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            main.log("error...");
            main.log(e.toString());
            main.main.stopConnection();
            interrupt();
        }
        while (!isInterrupted()){
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                interrupt();
                break;
            }
            main.log("ping");
        }
    }
}
```

I constructed these according to the Google Docs Guide.
Also on my Laptop i am doing the following:

[image]

And this is, what is happening on my Phone:
[image]

Here is, what is happening, when im trying to connect from my Windows PC:
[image]

As you can see on the phones screenshot i am stuck at `socket = serverSocket.accept()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UUID you are using is the UUID of the service - if you want to use the default RFCOMM channel you should use the SPP UUID `"00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"` instead of the `UUID.randomUUID();`

```
serverSocket = main.bAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Connection Test", UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
```

Comment: Ok thank you.. i didnt know i had to use a fixed UUID for this.. I was able to connect from the Windows PC. I am right, when i try to send messages via `echo TEXT > COM4` ?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it this way or use a HyperTerminal and connect through it. Wouldn't mind having the answer accepted as well ;)

Comment: mind another question?.. I now do have a Com Port "COM4" from my PC to my Phone, but the phone is still stuck on `checkPoint1` . When i try `echo Hello > COM4` the cmd says: "System cannot find that file". I also tried a connection via putty.. But putty abort with "Unable to open connection to COM4, Unable to open serial port"

Comment: you will have to open an input stream on the socket obtained
 socket.getInputStream(); then putty should be able to connect

Comment: But im not even getting past socket = serverSocket.accept(); :(

Comment: I will have to look at that later - I don't have my Bluetooth adapter available right now. What you are describing now seems like you might need to pair the devices first from the system menu. It sometimes happens. have you tried that?

Comment: They are paired. Thank you for your help though :)

Comment: I will try to look into that when I have access to my Bluetooth adapter

Comment: I got it working now.. i dont know how, but after some more trial and error it worked :D